# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DatePickerCtrl'

Tags: wxpython

In trying to learn, I am running code developed by others who indicate is it working.  It does not work for me.  I am attempting for the 1st time to use `wx.DatePickerCtrl`.  After running my code, I get the following error:

`test8000.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.datepick = wx.DatePickerCtrl(self.panel,-1, pos=(20,15),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DatePickerCtrl'`

I import wx upfront, assuming that is where `DatePickerCtrl` modules resides.
Thanks for any help - I am truly new at this.  I am using wxPython_Phoenix 3.0.3.dev78406 on a Windows 7 platform.  Michael

Comment: What version of wxPython? Which platform?

Comment: see answer on you your other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335543/is-datepickerctrl-been-update-to-work-with-python-3-4-wxpython-phoenix-3-0-3-an/29339981#29339981

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else comes across it.

On wxPython Phoenix (what you're using), the DatePickerCtrl is part of the wx.adv module.
On wxPython Classic, the DatePickerCtrl is part of the wx module. Your code was most likely written for WxPython Classic.

You can find a link to old installs [here](https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/).