# Is DatePickerCtrl been update to work with Python 3.4, wxPython_Phoenix 3.0.3 and Windows 7

Tags: wxpython

I am using Python 3.4, wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3 and windows 7 (64 bit).  I posted a prior issue with my system not recognizing wx.DatePickerCtrl providing the following message:  test8010.py", line 10, in **init**
    self.datepick = wx.DatePickerCtrl(self.panel,-1, pos=(20,15),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DatePickerCtrl'.

The it occurred to me that maybe DatePickerCtrl does not work with Python 3.4.  Does anyone know?
Thanks a bunch from a newby.

Michael

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but in Phoenix it is in wx.adv, see:
http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/adv.1classindex.html

Another good documentation page for changes in Phoenix is:
http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html

Comment: Are you aware of any good examples of this in use.  I seem to learn quicker by studying others examples.  Tutorials work wonders before and after I read books like wxPython In Action.

Comment: If you haven't already check out the wxPython demo, it shows a sample of each widget. I am not aware of a tutorial about this widget.